# Total applied to the lists: length of the object

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

My goal is to evaluate the total of each line of the following list:

```
f2 = {{c1, c2 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}, {c1, c2 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}, {c1, c2 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}, {c1, c2 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}, {c1, c2 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}, {c1, c2 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}, {c1, c2 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)], c3 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^2, c4 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^3, c5 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^4, c6 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}}
```

To achieve that, I have used.

```
In[31]:= f3 = Table[Total[f2[[l]]], {l, Length[f2]}] 
Out[31]= {c1 + c2 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T1)/(c^4 m^2)]^5, c1 + c2 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T2)/(c^4 m^2)]^5, c1 + c2 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T3)/(c^4 m^2)]^5, c1 + c2 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T4)/(c^4 m^2)]^5, c1 + c2 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T5)/(c^4 m^2)]^5, c1 + c2 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T6)/(c^4 m^2)]^5, c1 + c2 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)] + c3 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^2 + c4 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^3 + c5 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^4 + c6 Log[(En k T7)/(c^4 m^2)]^5}
```

This seems correct, but when I check the length of each element, this is.

```
In[32]:= Length[f3[[1]]]
Out[32]= 6
```

so, I can't use it as a list of 7 elements since it has a higher dimension. Do you know why? Is there a way to "flatter" these elements?

I tried also the function `Sum` but it works in the same way.

Comment: Check: `Dimensions@f3`

Comment: f3 has a length of 7. f3[[1]] is the first element of f3, consisting of a sum of 6 elements.

Comment: Try `Length[Plus[x, y, z]]`. It gives the length of any expression, not just of lists. Note that using the level spec, `Total[f2, {2}]`, yields `f3`.

Comment: Do you mean: "Total of each sublist" under the words: "total of each line of the following list?" If yes, try this: `Map[Total, f2]`.

Comment: In your example, `Length[f3[[1]]]` is 6 because there are six terms in the expression. See the $Scope$ section of the [`Length`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) documentation.